# Item.Editing.EndEdit() is not triggering save event when called from Powershell extension

Tags: powershell-extensions

We have written one rule for bucket items and it gets triggered when a bucket item is created or the item is saved.
for creating a bucket item we use below code

```
$updatedItem=New-Item -Path "$parentPath" -Name $Title -ItemType $Template
```

Now when the item is created, the rule is triggered which is expected. After that, I want to trigger the same rule again when the item's fields get updated. I have used the below code to update the item fields

```
$updatedItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
$updatedItem.Title=$NewsTitle      
$updatedItem.DateTime=$NewsDate
$updatedItem.Editing.EndEdit()
```

Now these fields get updated silently in sitecore but the save event is not fired and because of that the rule is not triggered.
I also used the below code to explicitly trigger the event but that too did not work.

```
$updatedItem.Editing.EndEdit($false,$true)
```

Is there any way where I can trigger the rule from PowerShell script or trigger the save event?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to trigger the Bucket Sync command after the edits are completed.

**Example:** The following syncs the bucketed items after the careers import finished and before publishing. This could take a while if there is a large number of items.

```powershell
Write-Verbose "Syncing jobs buckets."   
$careersBucketItem = Get-Item -Path $careersPSPath
[Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketManager]::Sync($careersBucketItem)
```

Comment: Hi Michael,  Thanks for your reply. That did not solve the issue either, after syncing the bucket it still not trigger the save event. So what  I would like to do is once item is created based on the date I want to change the location of the newly created item in the bucket using below line  ruleContext.ResolvedPath = date.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); So could you tell me how can this be done using powershell script. I used this line in the script but it did not work. [Sitecore.Buckets.Rules.Bucketing.BucketRuleContext]::ResolvedPath($articleDate)

Comment: Hi Michael, with your bucket sync code and few of code tweaks we were able to achieve what was expected. Thank you. However, as you mentioned it takes time as we have huge amount of data. I would like to use the BucketRuleContext's resolve path method but not sure how to do it in powershell script. ruleContext.ResolvedPath = date.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); If you could help would be great