# Force saving of an item

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-api

I have several newly added save events for existing items. Any way to force a save of an item? When I do `$item.Editing.BeginEdit()` / `$item.Editing.EndEdit()` in PowerShell it returns false since nothing changed.

Trying to think of a field I can update to trick into thinking it changed.

Comment: Whats the reason that you want to trigger save events even if the item fields didnt change?

Comment: The item save events are updating fields from other items. Like item A needs a calculation from items B and C. So I need Item A to run a save to trigger the event to do the calculations. Its easier than trying to rebuild the calculation code in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a very short answer.

But `$item.Editing.EndEdit($true, $false)` should do the trick.

The two parameters are

- updateStatistics
- silent

Setting `updateStatistics` to `true` SHOULD force Sitecore to write a new Modified Date, Modified By etc. and thus force a save of your item.

Setting `silent` to `true` would defeat your purpose, as it would supress events.

#### Edited to add

But also be aware of this. I'm not sure if there's an issue involving Sitecore Powershell Extensions or what's going on.

[Item.Editing.EndEdit() is not triggering save event when called from Powershell extension](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7930/item-editing-endedit-is-not-triggering-save-event-when-called-from-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the following code can be run from Powershell extensions, But i remember the following Sitecore API used to raise the Item:Saved events :

```
Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(this, new Sitecore.Data.Events.ItemSavedEventArgs(item));
```

Comment: This one worked for me:

$itemChanges = New-Object -TypeName "Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemChanges" -ArgumentList $_
$args = New-Object -TypeName "Sitecore.Data.Events.ItemSavingEventArgs" -ArgumentList $_, $itemChanges
[Sitecore.Events.Event]::RaiseItemSaving($this, $args)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is change `__Updated by` field to a value which you know that the item doesn't have, e.g. `sitecore\pse script`. Sitecore will think there is a change so it will execute all the events and update statistics, and it will set the `__Updated by` field to the current user value, ignoring the value which you use in the script, e.g.:

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item["__Updated by"] = "sitecore\pse script"
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

will result in

[image: Sitecore powershell force saving item]

If you run that script as Admin.